# How can I measure the performance of scripts correctly?

Tags: php

I have the following example with two script versions:

```
$string = "It is test string for performance";

// VERSION 1

$time_start = microtime(true); 
$explode = explode(' ', $string);
foreach ($explode as $s) {
    echo $s . "<br />";
}

$time_end = microtime(true);

$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;

echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins <br />';

// VERSION 2

$time_start2 = microtime(true); 

foreach (explode(' ', $string) as $s) {
    echo $s . "<br />";
}

$time_end2 = microtime(true);

$execution_time2 = ($time_end2 - $time_start2)/60;

echo '<b>Total Execution Time 2:</b> '.$execution_time2.' Mins <br />';
```

I would like to measure which version of the script is more efficient, but I get strange results. Even if I swap both scripts, the second one always has a longer execution time. For example:

```
It
is
test
string
for
performance
Total Execution Time: 1.5099843343099E-7 Mins
It
is
test
string
for
performance
Total Execution Time 2: 6.3578287760417E-8 Mins
```

How can I best measure the performance of such scripts?

Comment: What do you mean by longer? `6.3578287760417E-8 Mins` means your second code is faster than first which took `1.5099843343099E-7 Mins` to complete.

Comment: So why explode within foreach is faster than variable? I have always read that it should be done the other way around.

Comment: @nafigoh Perhaps because it doesn't need to "write" the data to variable, it just holds it in the loop then it's "gone"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not odd at all. The times that is outputed is scientific.

```
1.5099843343099E-7 Mins
```

is the same as

```
0.00000015099843343099 minutes
```

And that sounds correct.
To output that string should be very fast, which it seems to be also.

It's not uncommon at all to get slightly different result on the same code.
It depends on CPU and memory of the computer, if a background task runs just as one of the codes run it can make a difference.

---

Answer to your comment:

```
$string = "It is test string for performance";

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $time_start = microtime(true); 
    $explode = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach ($explode as $s) {
        echo $s . "<br />";
    }

    $time_end = microtime(true);

    $execution_time[] = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;


    $time_start2 = microtime(true); 

    foreach (explode(' ', $string) as $s) {
        echo $s . "<br />";
    }

    $time_end2 = microtime(true);

    $execution_time2[] = ($time_end2 - $time_start2)/60;
}

var_dump($execution_time, $execution_time2);
```

This should give you a hint of what is the best/fastest. But then again it's such a small difference I doubt you notice it.
https://3v4l.org/6LcIg

Comment: Thanks, so how can I find confirmation that it is better to make a separate variable than to directly call explode in foreach?

Comment: @nafigoh run it n number of times and see if the result is always the same. you could loop your loops in a for loop and save the times in arrays that you var dump. see edit